# Can't call Given, When or Then from inside a SpecFlow step definition

Tags: c#, specflow

I have a step definition in which I wish to call another step, but it will not compile:

```
    [Given(@"I am on the (.*) page")]
    public void GivenIAmOnThePage(string url)
    {
        Given(@"I click the login button"); // cannot find this Given() SpecFlow library method
    }
```

When building I get:

```
The name 'Given' does not exist in the current context
```

I have this using statement and VS does not suggest any others to complete the code:

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
```

Comment: If such a `Given` exists, it'll probably be called `GivenIClickTheLoginButton`. If it doesn't, then, well, you haven't created it yet. If you want to find out what `Given` it would be *dynamically*, that's another kettle of fish, but that sort of dependency would be very brittle.

Comment: Incidentally, it seems particularly odd and inappropriate to call "I click the login button" from "I am on the page". This is the sort of thing you write in your specification, not as part of the method call. What you're saying with calling the method is "if I am on the page, then it must be the case that I clicked the login button", and that's the sort of thing you would want to have explicit in your spec. Otherwise, it's probably more appropriate to factor out common implementation code to a separate method and call it from both `Given`s, rather than chaining them.

Comment: It's not the step method I'm trying to call which is the problem - it's literally the 'Given()' SpecFlow method... the one which enables calling steps from within other steps.

Comment: There is no such method. You're confusing it with `GivenAttribute`, which just tells SpecFlow how to map scenario text to a method. The methods themselves all have specific names.

Comment: S'ok, found it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the inheritance of the `TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps` class...

```
public class PageNavigation : Steps
{
    ...
}
```